# Knowing if a file is binary or text

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

After a file has been placed on to the server is there any way to determine whether the file is binary or text? A ColdFusion function along the lines of `FileIsBinary()` would be nice but I can't find anything like this.

I need to know so I can determine whether or not to use `<cffile action="read"...>` or `<cfile action="readBinary"...>`

Would trying `<cfile action="readBinary"...>` in a `<cftry>` block and catching any errors be a reliable way of determining that a file is text?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no simple / guaranteed method. Can you provide a little more background about your use case? How is the file "placed on the server" - via upload? Why do you need to differentiate between text/binary?

Comment: How about looking at the file extension?  Would it be safe to assume that the file extension would properly identify the type of file it is?

Comment: The file is placed on the server by upload. I need to be able to encrypt both types of file and believe I need to handle the encryption of the two file types differently.

Comment: Just use FileReadBinary to read in the files as binary, and use [encryptBinary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e75.html) on the bytes.

Comment: I didn't know there was an encryptBinary function, thanks Leigh!

Comment: It depends on your exact use case, but I would try treating all kinds of file as binary if you're going to be encrypting them. unencrypting them should result in an identical file, regardless of content type which may well be what you want

Comment: *I didn't know there was an encryptBinary function* [Functions by category view](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6907) is your friend ;-)

Comment: Having encrypted a PNG file using encryptBinary I get an error when I use decryptBinary to unencrypt it. The error is 'An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: Invalid padding'. Does anybody know what the cause of this might be?